# FB fan_page likes works in Chrome but not in C#

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using api version 2.7 and this command I get the right data back:

https://graph.facebook.com/FANPAGE_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=name,fan_count

But when I try this in C# with this command:

client.println ("GET https://graph.facebook.com/FANPAGE_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=name,fan_count")

I get a much longer html file back with only the graphic box information and no numeric info about the page likes. Has anyone an idea how I can get the same info back like in Chrome ?

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the API version. `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/…`

Comment: I want to use the latest version 2.7.